# How can i use the result of one mysql query and use it in another query in php?

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to get a result from on table and use this result in a query on another table. How can i pass this result as binding parameter? I am posting the required variable from android studio and receiving it in php code.

Here is my code:

```
<?php
    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","2015","testdatabase") or die("Error Connecting" . mysqli_error($link));
    if (!$con)
    {
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error());
    }
    $Customer = $_POST["Customer"];

    $statement = mysqli_prepare($con,"SELECT id FROM Customer WHERE Customer = ?");
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement,"s",$Customer);
    $result = mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);

    if (!$result) 
    {
        echo 'Could not run query: ' . mysql_error();
        exit;
    }
    $row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
    $statemente = mysqli_prepare($con,"SELECT * FROM comments WHERE c_id = ? ORDER BY DESC id");
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statemente,"s",$row[0]);
    $resultt=mysqli_stmt_execute($statemente);
    while($roww = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultt))
    {
        $output[]=$roww;
    }
    echo(json_encode($output));
    mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: What error are you facing now with your code?

Comment: @HosseinShahsahebi  is it the correct way? because im not getting the output

Comment: You wouldn't do this. Instead you would use a JOIN

Comment: I recommend you, after you fill `$row`, print it and see the indexes. I thing there must be something like `$row[0]['id']` when you want to use it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the result by on one sql statement

```
SELECT c.*
FROM `Customer` u INNER JOIN `comments` c ON u.id = c.c_id
ORDER BY c.c_id DESC
```

**or** assemble the ids from `$rows` with `implode()`

```
$id = implode($rows, ',');
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statemente, "s", $id);
```

the modified sql like below:

```
SELECT * FROM comments WHERE c_id in ? ORDER BY id DESC
```

Comment: thanks a lot, that was pretty precise. Although can you help me with one thing? I cam up with the following statement myself on some research:

SELECT comments.comment,comments.TimeStamp,comments.deviceID FROM comments,Customer WHERE comments.c_id = (SELECT c_id FROM Customer WHERE Customer.Conf= 'test')

I want to get that c_id from customer which has conf = 'test', and then get all details related to that c_id from comments table. But this statement is iterating itself c_id number of times. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: you don't need the Customer table in FROM condition